# In javascript, spliting a string with order preserving

Tags: javascript

```
hosts=".uk.com:hostname:@10.10.10.10/10:@[2001:db8:1/64]:@11.11.11.11/11:@[::2/24]"
```

In javascript, how do i split the above string("hosts") string like the following :

```
newhosts=.uk.com,hostname,@10.10.10.10/10,@[2001:db8:1/64],@11.11.11.11/11,@[::2/24]"
```

tried this :

```
var hosts, newhosts;
var ip6_hosts = [];
var ip6_re = /@\[(.*?)\]/g;

hosts=".uk.com:hostname:@10.10.10.10/10:@[2001:db8:1/64]:@11.11.11.11/11:@[::2/24]";
while ((match=ip6_re.exec(hosts)) != null)
    ip6_hosts.push(match[0]);
non_ip6_hosts=hosts.replace(ip6_re, '').replace(/:+/g, ':');
newhosts=ip6_hosts.concat(non_ip6_hosts.split(':'));
```

actual output :

```
newhosts=@[2001:db8:1/64],@[::2/24],.uk.com,hostname,@10.10.10.10/10,@11.11.11.11/11
```

expected output :

```
newhosts=.uk.com,hostname,@10.10.10.10/10,@[2001:db8:1/64],@11.11.11.11/11,@[::2/24]
```

but not sure how to preserve the order. is there any way to achieve an expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
    var openbracket=0;
    for (i=0; i<hosts.length; i++)
    {
    if (hosts.substr(i,1) == '[') openbracket=openbracket+1;
    if (hosts.substr(i,1) == ']') openbracket=openbracket-1;
            if ((hosts.substr(i,1) == ':') && openbracket==0)
            {
            hosts = hosts.substr(0,i) + ',' + hosts.substr(i+1,hosts.length-i-1);
            }
    }
```

seems to work for me, though I'm not sure if there's a better method for changing the value of hosts. All it needs to do is insert the ',' at the location i. The above code adds everything to the left of the ':', a ',', and everything to the right of the ':'.
note: this assumes you don't want any ':' inside of brackets changed to a comma.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can't You just say:

```
host = host.replace(/:+/, ',');
```

whenever you want to change it?
I feel like this is too simple of an answer, comment if I'm not getting it.

Comment: This is exactly how I interpret it as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that also replace the double colin at the end with two commas, which his example shows shouldn't be replaced?

Comment: @aaronfrost very true. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
hosts.replace(/([^:]{1})\:{1}([^:]{1})/g, '$1,$2')
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, cause you don't want the colins in the brackets to be replaced with commas. Let me try again.

Comment: This doesn't work exactly. It is like most of the other answers. They are close, but not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this...

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
```

}

hosts=".uk.com:hostname:@10.10.10.10/10:@[2001:db8:1/64]:@11.11.11.11/11:@[::2/24]"

hosts = hosts.split(':@').join(',@');

var re = /:\w/g;
var found = hosts.match(re);

hosts.replaceAt(found.index,',');

Comment: This is close. The target that the user wants should also replace the colin between "com" and "hostname". They should become "com,hostname", per the question. This is very close. You could do it in one line of code, also, so I like this.

Comment: hosts=".uk.com:hostname:@10.10.10.10/10:@[2001:db8:1/64]:@11.11.11.11/11:@[::2/24]"
Oh yes... I missed that.. This should give the expected output.
hosts = hosts.split(':@').join(',@');
var re = /:\w/;
var match = hosts.match(re);
hosts.replaceAt(match.index,',');

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var hosts='.uk.com:hostname:@10.10.10.10/10:@[2001:db8:1/64]:@11.11.11.11/11:@[::2/24]';

hosts = hosts.replace(/:@/g, ':@@');
hosts = hosts.split(':@');

var hostDetails = hosts[0].split(':');

var newHost = hostDetails.concat(hosts.splice(1, hosts.length));

console.log(newHost);
```

Comment: this is close but not cover the case of order change. for example, it doesn't generate the expected output if the string 'hostname' is at the end.